# Outdoor images from Google Street View API

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

We are using Google Street View Image API (not the Javascript API) to construct a URL which returns a street view image. The problem is, that sometimes it returns an image of the inside of the building, rather than the image of the building at the provided address, e.g.:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=KOMPHAUSBADSTRASSE,%20AACHEN,%20DE&source=outdoor&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=Your_api_key

Is there any solution/workaround, to only show outdoor images?

Comment: source is not supported for the Web Api, only works for the JS API

Comment: The corresponding feature request in Google issue tracker is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826865. Feel free to star it to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.

Comment: This issue was raised almost 3 years ago - got caught up in semantics as to whether it was a feature or a bug and passed around internally within Google. Disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

Good news. Google implemented [feature request 35826865](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826865) and added new `source` parameter in Street View Image API.

> **source** - (default is default) limits Street View searches to selected sources. Valid values are:
>
> - **default** uses the default sources for Street View; searches are not limited to specific sources.
> - **outdoor** limits searches to outdoor collections. Indoor collections are not included in search results. Note that outdoor panoramas may not exist for the specified location. Also note that the search only returns panoramas where it's possible to determine whether they're indoors or outdoors. For example, PhotoSpheres are not returned because it's unknown whether they are indoors or outdoors.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro

I have tried your sample request, but it looks like unfortunately Google doesn't have outdoor street view panoramas in this area.

If you try a street view metadata with outdoor parameter

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?location=KOMPHAUSBADSTRASSE%2C%20AACHEN%2C%20DE&source=outdoor&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

you will get zero results in the response

```
{
    "status":"ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

You can also see it in Geocoder tool if you drag a pagman in this area

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DKOMPHAUSBADSTRASSE%252C%2520AACHEN%252C%2520DE

There are no street view outdoor imagery in this area as you can see in the screenshot

[image]